# How to replace string in all project with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: replace

I would like to replace one string with another in the whole project but I can't find anywhere how to enable the replace option in VSC (Visual Studio Code). Could someone tell me how I can enable this option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

The command is Ctrl + Shift + H (ir in Edit>Replace in files)

[image]